# find an element from a drop down list using webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a simple automated test application, I have reach a point where I have to write an n unit test for the application.

My question is I want to assert a value select by the user with a default value from the system, can someone give me a hand to do that please

This is my code :

```
IWebElement dropDownListBox = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlWorkflow"));
dropDownListBox.Click();
Assert.AreEqual(-1, string.Compare("CD-A", dropDownListBox.Text, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown is referred as `Select Element` in Selenium. In order to select the item from the list, we need to use `SelectElement` class of Selenium and it is part of `WebDriver.Support.dll`. Try the below code.

```
SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlWorkflow")));

selectElement.SelectByText(dropdown item text); // Or can use Index
selectElement.SelectByIndex(dropdown item index);
```

For getting the drop down item selected text, need to use the below.

```
selectElement.SelectedOption.Text;
```

So your final code would look like this.

```
Assert.AreEqual("CD-A", selectElement.SelectedOption.Text, "Dropdown item should be selected.");
```

Do let me know if this works for you.